# Unable to fetch record from second table using yii AR

Tags: yii

! have two model classes
1-Usermaster 
2-Userinstances
usermaster having multiple userinstances.

I want all the related record from both tables,i have done like that
**Usermaster.php(model class)**

```
public function relations()
    {   
    return array(
        'userinstances' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Userinstances', 'Id')
    );
    }
```

**userinstances.php(model class) -**

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                     'usermaster' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Usermaster', 'userMasterID')
        );
    }
```

**In MyController.php**

```
 $resultSettmp = Usermaster ::model()->with('userinstances')->findAll();
```

but it is giving the record from only Usermaster and userinstances as blank array,Is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: did you try `together` option in relation?

Comment: In a relation, always mention a FK, not the PK as you did in the first model;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your relations are not right. Try it like this:

In Ubermaster:

```
public function relations()
{   
    return array(
        'userinstances' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Userinstances', 'userMasterID')
    );
}
```

And userinstances.php(model class) -

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'usermaster' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Usermaster', 'userMasterID')
    );
}
```

I changed the foreign key in the userinstances relation.

Comment: and i think that the type is also wrong, because the first is 1 to many, and the second is many to 1

Comment: Hi veelen,
Its work for me,i have changed the foreign key and also change the relation of first one to HAS_MANY and 2nd one to HAS_ONE.